# Marcus-SDE to Itô-SDE

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

In the field of stochastic calculus, everyone knows the Itô and Stratonovich integrals, as well as the conversion from Stratonovich to Itô SDEs.
The Stratonovich integration has the particularity of behaving like classical calculus (obeying the chain rule); however, in the presence of jumps, a corrective term must be added, and the new 'integration' is called Marcus integration.

Basically when we have $(Z_t)_{t \geq 0} $ $\mathbb{R}$-valued semimartingale and $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}) $. An adapted stochastic process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is called solution of the Marcus type stochastic differential equation generated by $(f,(Z_t)_{t \geq 0})$, if $(X_t)_{ t \geq 0}$
\begin{align*}
    X_t = {} & X_0 + \int_0^t f(X_s)\diamond\mathrm{d}Z_s\\
    = {} & X_0 + \int_0^t f(X_s)\circ\mathrm{d}Z_s^c + \int_0^t f(X_{s-}) \, \mathrm{d}Z_s^d \\
& + \sum_{0 < s \leq t } \Big(\exp(f \, \Delta Z_s,X_{s-},1) -  X_{s-} - f(X_{s-}) \, \Delta Z_s \Big) 
\end{align*}
where $\exp(g,x,v)$ is solution of the ordinary differential equation,
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\mathrm{d}Y(u)}{\mathrm{d}u} &= g(Y(u))\\
    Y(0) &= x
\end{align*}
at time $u = v$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now, if we consider simplest case when $Z_t = N_t$ for $(N_t)_{t \geq 0}$ simple Poisson counting process, and translate the following Marcus-SDE to Itô-SDE,
$$X_t = \int_{0}^{t} X_{s-}\diamond \mathrm{d}N_s$$
Using conversion,
\begin{align*}
    X_t &=  \int_0^1 X_{s-} \, \mathrm{d}N_s + \sum_{0 \leq s \leq t} \Big(\exp(g \, \Delta N_s,X_{s-},1) - X_{s-} - X_{s-} \, \Delta N_{s-}\Big)
\end{align*}
Here two ODE to solve,
When
$$\Delta N_s = 0,$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}Y(u)}{\mathrm{d}u} &= 0,\\
&\quad\quad\quad \to Y(u) = x\\
Y(0) &= x
\end{align*}

When
$$ \Delta N_s = 1, $$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}Y(u)}{\mathrm{d}u} &= Y(u)\\
&\quad\quad\quad \to Y(u) = xe^u \\
Y(0) &= x
\end{align*}
So,
\begin{align*}
X_t &= \int_0^1 X_{s-} \, \mathrm{d}N_s + \sum_{0 \leq s \leq t} \Bigg(\Delta N_s X_{s-}e^1 + (1 - \Delta N_s) X_{s-} - X_{s-} - X_{s-}\Delta N_{s-}\Bigg)\\
X_t &= (e^1 - 1)\int_0^1 X_{s-} \, \mathrm{d}N_s
\end{align*}

Is this calculus correct?